# Downloading a file using WireMoc

Tags: unit-testing, testing, wiremock

I'm new to WireMoc. How do i go about Downloading a file using WireMoc stubbing framework?
This is what i have so far

```
     var stub = FluentMockServer.Start(new FluentMockServerSettings
        {
            Urls = new[] { "http://+:5001" },
            StartAdminInterface = true
        });

     stub.Given(
                Request.Create()
                    .WithPath("/myFile")
                    .UsingPost()
                    .WithBody("download file"))
            .RespondWith(Response.Create()
                .WithStatusCode(200)
                .WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/multipart")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use withBodyFile api of wiremock

```
stubFor(get(urlEqualTo("/body-file"))
        .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withBodyFile("path/to/myfile.xml")));
```

However

> To read the body content from a file, place the file under the __files directory. By default this is expected to be under src/test/resources when running from the JUnit rule. When running standalone it will be under the current directory in which the server was started. To make your stub use the file, simply call bodyFile() on the response builder with the file’s path relative to __files:

But you can set custom path while starting wiremock using

```
wireMockServer = new WireMockServer(wireMockConfig().port(portNumber).usingFilesUnderClasspath("src/main/resources/"));
```

Now it will look for files in /src/main/resources/__files/

The source for above information

http://wiremock.org/docs/stubbing/

https://github.com/tomakehurst/wiremock/issues/129